# Bootstrap calender inside popup not working in chrome

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

In popup, bootstrap calender is working in firefox but not in chrome

**My html is as follows:**

```
 <label for="text-input">Birth Date</label>
  <div id="txtBirthDate" class=" input-group date dp-ex-4" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd.mm.yyyy" data-date-autoclose="true" data-date-start-view="2">
   <input class="form-control" type="text">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
  </div>
```

Can any one help?

Answer (score 0):

**@User3724793** Do You use javascript for BootStarp Calender if not please use this one..

```
     $.extend($.fn.datepicker.defaults, {
         parse: function (string) {
             var matches;
             if ((matches = string.match(/^(\d{2,2})\/(\d{2,2})\/(\d{4,4})$/))) {
                 return new Date(matches[3], matches[1] - 1, matches[2]);
             } else {
                 return null;
             }
         },
         format: function (date) {
             var
         month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString(),
         dom = date.getDate().toString();
             if (month.length === 1) {
                 month = "0" + month;
             }
             if (dom.length === 1) {
                 dom = "0" + dom;
             }
             return month + "/" + dom + "/" + date.getFullYear();
         }
     });
</script>
```

Comment: and also use bootstarp.css on your page

Answer (score 0):

try adding this style to your html page

```
<style>
```

.datepicker{z-index:1151;}